# Offered admit to grad school but having second thoughts about attending at all

Tags: masters, etiquette, career-path

As my undergraduate years (Bachelor in Electrical Engineering) were coming to a close, I applied to a few universities in the US for Masters, mostly because that's what everyone does. I didn't think too much about what I'd like to study, was quite doubtful while applying (was told to just apply and see what happens) - was wanting to take a year off to work, really be sure about what I want to do in life, be sure of the field in which I wanted to apply. However, I went ahead and applied anyway.

I have received an acceptance from a rather well-reputed University for engineering, though without funding, and am now seriously wondering if I can turn it down. I can't seem to find anyone else who did this - applied without considering seriously and now wants to turn down the offer, but doesn't feel good about it because it's a good university. However, the amount of money involved is making me think four times before accepting, since once I accept, not only will I be obligated to work my ass off, take up part-time jobs, but will also have to work to pay that money off. It seems to potentially be a very expensive mistake to make, and I want to be absolutely sure that I'm willing and really wanting to give it my all, and not enter the programme half-heartedly. As it stands, I am regretting having applied in the first place.

Do you have any advice for me, what I should consider, what I'm failing to look at, whether I'm a complete brat for doing this?

Comment: There are currently two ways to interpret your question: (1) Is it unheard of and bad etiquette to turn down an offer? Answer: No, and even if so, you don't want to base life-altering decisions on questions of etiquette. (2) What is the right choice for me in terms of career and education? Only you can answer this broad question, and that's why on this reading I nominate the question for closure. Perhaps you can rework the question to make it fit the criteria of the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: _"(was told to just apply and see what happens)""As it stands, I am regretting having applied in the first place."_ That's something that (as a highly indecisive person) I have found to have affected/affect/will affect many aspects of my life. No matter what you do, which as @henning said is solely your decision, think **twice** in the future before applying to anything that you are not willing to follow or you think you will not be able to pull through. _"mostly because that's what everyone does"_ Also, that's a big **no-no** reason to do basically _anything_.

Answer (score 3):

It's obvious that your true inclination is to turn down the offer, so that's what you should do. All the reasons you cite for why you are reluctant to follow that course of action have to do not with what you really want for yourself but with an unhealthy preoccupation with what others are doing or will think of you: you mention applying "because that's what everyone does", that "you can't seem to find anyone else who did this", and that you are worried about being a "complete brat for doing this". Sorry, but these are all bad reasons for doing or not doing something. So, unless you have a genuinely compelling reason to take the offer based on what *you* want for yourself rather than a fear of disappointing or upsetting someone else, this decision is a complete no-brainer.